# IOS scrollview is not clickable

Tags: ios, marquee

Here is my code:

```
int i = 0;
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.exclusiveTouch = YES;


self.canCancelContentTouches = YES;
self.delaysContentTouches = YES;
self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gototest)];
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
for (NSString *message in self.messages) {
    UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    label.text = message;
    label.tag = i;
    CGSize size = [message sizeWithFont:label.font];
    CGFloat width = size.width + kPADDING;
    label.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 0.0, width, self.frame.size.height);
    [self addSubview:label];

    i++;

    xPos += width;
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(label.frame));
}
self.messagesWidth = xPos;
self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(xPos, self.frame.size.height);
self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(-self.frame.size.width, 0.0);

}

-(void)gototest
{
NSLog(@"test %@",@"ccc ");
}
```

and then for marquee 
   - (void)go {

```
if (!self.period) self.period = self.messagesWidth / 100;
// so it always takes about the same (fudged, but reasonable) amount of time to scroll    the whole array

[UIView animateWithDuration:self.period
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear  |UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
                     self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.messagesWidth, 0.0);
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
 }
```

So, my goal is to create a marquee for news and each news be clickable to see the details of the clicked new.

but the UITapGestureRecognizer doesnt work and I dont know why.

Note that self is scrollview because my class extend from UIScrollView.

So please help me

Comment: hi @Limon for me i dont care about the label, I need that the scrollview be clickable.

Comment: how do you mean _clickable_? in iOS there is no such an event like _click_, we are working with _touches_ and _gestures_ here.

Comment: hi @holex I mean like touches so when i touch the scrollview nothing happen

Comment: the `UIScrollView` usually 'steals' the gestures from you, but you can define dependencies between the gesture recognisers. that may help on your problem when you try to add a new recogniser next to the current ones. that documentation is defintely helpful for you achieving it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to subclass `UIScrollView` in the following way. Then use your custom scroll view (i.e. `TouchScrollView`) instead of the regular `UIScrollView`

**TouchScrollView.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import UIKit;

@interface TouchScrollView : UIScrollView

@end
```

**TouchScrollView.m:**

```
#import "TouchScrollView.h"

@implementation TouchScrollView

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // Respond to touch events here
    // ...


    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

@end
```

Or if you want to do it in Swift since it's the fashion nowadays:

**TouchScrollView.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TouchScrollView: UIScrollView {
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        // Respond to touch events here
        // ...
        nextResponder().touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        nextResponder().touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {
        nextResponder().touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
    }
}
```

Comment: if you add an `NSLog("HIT")` to the touchesBegan method, you get no output when you touch the scrollview?